# Babel problem while having a local node modules in my src folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I have created a local node module and I have configured the webpack to consider this module (module is in src/component):

```
 modules: ['node_modules', 'src/components'].concat(
        process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
      )
```

While starting the project, babel does not transpile my react stateless function and I get an unexpeted token error in my jsx syntax.
When I don't use a node module and I remove the local package.json file, everything works fine.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Babel's [documentation for monorepo structures](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos) (repos with multiple packages).

The short answer is, convert your `.babelrc` to a `babel.config.js` file and put that in your project root. `.babelrc` files are scoped to a specific package, so there is no way to use a `.babelrc` to configure your `src/components/foo` package.